# streaming api functionality to keep the application on the non-salesforce server up to date quicker

Tags: api

We have an application that communicates with another application on a different server. From my understanding, due to governor limits to api calls, the application caches all updates from the salesforce cloud once with one api call. We would like to utilize the streaming api functionality to keep the application on the non-salesforce server up to date quicker. How to achieve this.

Comment: This is really two questions. Can you make number two a separate question? Each question should be one topic.  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Two questions means twice the potential rep points too! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can establish [PushTopics](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/pushtopic.htm) to send modifications on some pre defined objects using Streaming API, but have in mind that the size of the notifications can be small and sometimes not enough to send all the information trough push notifications.

Please see the limitations of the [Streaming API here](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api_streaming/Content/limits.htm).

Another alternative not that quick as streaming API but less limited in length is [Outbound Messaging](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging.htm).